# How to handle modal/ pop-up using automation

Tags: selenium, modal-dialog, popup, alert

Tried to handle the pop-up many ways, need clarity do we need to change the body. because when the pop-up is displayed the new class is adding it is as below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQC2B.png
The actual Pop-up class is as below. there is no close button for this pop-up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1ZWc.png
-By manual user can close the pop-up when user click any where in the page. When i tried click any where  using automation it is displaying as element not found

- Here is the code i user to handle the pop-up i am so confused how to handle the pop-up
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibf0j.png

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Can you share page url ?

Comment: Current url provided by the company belong to dev environment.. will try to find the live url and share with you... Thank you for taking time looking at my question

Comment: Hi Cruisepandey, the live url of the site is https://orcharddelivery.beta.dropdelivery.com/, Please help me out...

Comment: I see this `This app is no longer active
Call  (555) 666-0606  for more information` is that the pop up ? there is no ways to close that pop up manually.

Comment: looks like there is some internal issues and server down.

Answer (score 0):

please try to check the javascript from where this pop-up is executing and try to disable display property by setting it to none

Try to remove this div class name "_355Q0" from DOM. by using this javascript query.

```
var myobj = document.querySelector("._355Q0")
myobj.remove();
```

Comment: Hi Zafar Abbas, Thank you for your replay i never worked with java script is there any reference which i can follow and come up with solution

Comment: Try to remove this div class name "_355Q0" from DOM. by using this javascript query.
var myobj = document.querySelector("._355Q0")
myobj.remove();